# Add large files (exe, dlls, xmls) into cells of tables in mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, ampps

If I want to store files like exe, dll and xml large files in a cell of a table inside a database, is it possible to do?
If yes, how can it be done? and is it common practice to do so?
I am using mySQL database using ampps.

Comment: yes, blobs, no.

Comment: ok, thanks. @Sirko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use blob type column to store files in mySql but this is not recommended when thousands of file will stored in db then it is difficult to manage database. you should create repository some where in server and create file with database id.